# Rails model validation value of field if a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model called Ticked, in this model I have several fields but I need to work with two fields (official [bool] and code[string]).

I need to make sure that the official value can't change to true if the value of the codes are "AP" or "CP" if the code is different, the official value can be true or false.

How can I do this? I've been looking for this but can't find anything.

edit:

I tried this:

```
  def validate_codes
    if official && ["AP", "CP"].include? code
      errors.add(:official, 'cant be true because of the codes')
    end
  end
```

but doesn't work

edit 2:

I change the code like this, now the method doesn't throw an error but I can update the model without any problems...

```
  def validate_codes
    if self.official && ( self.code == "AP" || self.code == "CP")
      self.errors.add(:official, "Can't be official because of its code")
    end
  end
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [custom methods section of the official Rails guide on validations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods)?

Comment: @FabianWinkler  i read that but i cant find to use it propperly, I added my code, can you check it please?

Comment: @Stefan yeah, sorry haha it was a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

```
validates :official, inclusion: [ false ], if: Proc.new{|i| ["AP", "CP"].include?(i.code) }
```

This will force `self.official` to be `false` if the code is either `AP` or `CP`.

Comment: Thank you so much!